# Content.Load does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, xna

I'm going through this tutorial on SoundEffect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195053.aspx However, I'm getting the error from the compiler that "Content" doesn't exist in the current context.

Here's the code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio; 
using Microsfot.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace SoundTouchTest 
{
     class SoundTouchTest
     {
            public void loadContent()
            {
                  SoundEffect s; 
                  s = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("example"); 
            }
     }
}
```

I've successfully added the references (or at least I think that I have).Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Once try `using Microsfot.Xna.Framework;` instead of `using Microsfot.Xna.Framework.Content;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Content` **is a property** that usually refers to an instance of type [`ContentManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.aspx) inside a [`Game`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.aspx) class. Since your `SoundTouchTest` class isn't a `Game`, it **doesn't have that property**.

You should **pass the `ContentManager` instance as a parameter** to your `loadContent()` method:

```
void loadContent(ContentManager content)
{
    SoundEffect e = content.Load<SoundEffect>("example");
}
```

Somewhere inside your `Game` class:

```
SoundTouchTest soundTouchTest = new SoundTouchTest();
soundTouchTest.loadContent(this.Content);
```

Comment: Awesome, that makes perfect sense, thanks! However, when I call the static void Main() method in that class and create an instance like yours, the compiler doesn't like this. Sorry, it's been a while, so how would I fix this? :(

Comment: Is this an XNA Game Project we're talking about?

Comment: Not really, honestly, but if it needs to be, I suppose I can make it? I just wanted to test this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940201.aspx. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should use XNA Game Project for XNA related examples. Then following that msdn sample will be pretty straightforward. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! After working through it with XNA, it worked!

Comment: Thanks! This is a very confusing part of XNA/Monogame since it looks like you are invoking a class method (Content.Load) while it's actually a property of your Game class!

Answer (score 2):

You could either pass `ContentManager` in as parameter through loadContent and then call loadContent in the load method found in game1 or you could create a new instance of it (which I wouldn't recommend, you wouldn't want to create a new object every time you need to load something when the objects already been created for you).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Content.Load it should really be ContentManager.Load

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx

You may need to create an instance of Content Manager however to use it